# Integration is zero implies $g$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $g$ be a monotone function such that
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) \,dg(x) \,dg(y)=0$$
where $f(x,y)= 1$ if $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$ otherwise it is $0$.

The integration is w.r.t. Riemann-Stieltjes sense. How can we show that $g$ is continuous?

My try:

If $g$ is not continuous at $c$, $g$ can have only jump discontinuity at $c$ . I am not being able to use this fact.
Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update:
If $f$ is not continuous at a point $c \in (0,1)$.
Let us choose $\epsilon>0$ such that, $(c-\epsilon, c+ \epsilon) \subset (0,1)$.
Then,
$$ 0=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) \,dg(x) \,dg(y) \geq \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,x) \,dg(x) \,dg(x)=
 \int_0^1 \int_0^1  \,dg(x) \,dg(x) = [  \int_0^1  \,dg(x) ]^2 \geq [  \int_{c -\epsilon}^{c+ \epsilon}  \,dg(x) ]^2 = [g(c+\epsilon)- g(c-\epsilon)]^2 >0$$, which is a contradiction. Thus $g$ is continuous at $c\in (0,1)$.

If $g$ is not continuous at $0$, then
$$ 0=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) \,dg(x) \,dg(y) \geq [g(\epsilon)- g(0)]^2 >0$$, a contradiction.

If $g$ is not continuous at $1$, then
$$ 0=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) \,dg(x) \,dg(y) \geq [ g(1)- 
g(1-\epsilon)]^2 >0$$, a contradiction.

Thus, $g$ is continuous on [0,1].

I want  to justify the step
$$ 0=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) \,dg(x) \,dg(y) \geq \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,x) \,dg(x) \,dg(x)$$ with proof and hope the other parts are correct.

Any help or hint will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried computing $\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y) dg(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

If $g$ is not continuous at some $0< c\le 1$ then, without loss of generality, $g(x)=I(x-c)$ so that $g$ has one and only one unit jump at $x=c.$

Now, $f=0$ except on the corners of the unit square and the diagonal, where $f=1.$ Then since $f(c,c)=1$, we see that $\int_0^1f(x,c)dI(x-c)$ does not exist, because $f$ has a discontinuity at the point where $g$ has a jump.

Comment: The continuity of $g$ does not imply $dg$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.  The Cantor function is continuous, but $dg$ is singular.  (Otherwise, I agree.)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Coukd you please elaborate little more?

Comment: On boundary $f=1?$ I think $f=1$ only on the diagonal and on $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$

Comment: How are you defining $g$ . $g$ is already given. Is not it? Kindly explain more.

Comment: @mathisfun yes, on the corners and the diagonal. I am saying that if $g$ has a jump discontinuity then without loss of generality, you may as well assume it has the form $I(x-c)$. It is just easier to visualize that way. You do not need to do this though Just take any such $g$ and note that the inner integral $\int_0^1f(x,c)dg(x)$ does not exist because the function $x\mapsto f(x,c)$ has a discontinuity at the jump.

Comment: Still didn't get it. Can you pls have a look at what I tried?

Comment: the very first inequality is not true (unless I am missing something). For instance, if $g$ is Lebesgue measure the integral is zero because $f=0$ a.e. But $ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,x) \,dg(x) \,dg(x)= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 1 \,dg(x) \,dg(x)>0.$

Comment: You need to show that if $f$ is discontinuous at the jump, then the integral does not exist. You can do this easily  if you believe my wlog assumption.